# See what files are growing in a directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filesystems

Does someone have a shell script or utility that can monitor a specific directory and see which file is growing within a certain time period and possibly by how much?

For example, if I have the following files in a directory:

```
myfile1.txt
anotherfile.gz
thisonetoo.tar
```

The script could be run once, and then on the next run time it might say something like

```
myfile1.txt +5MB
anotherfile.gz -10MB
thisonetoo.tar +100MB
```

Comment: I guess this was considered off topic because it's better on ServerFault.com??

Comment: Similar question https://serverfault.com/questions/332948/how-to-find-growing-files-inside-a-linux-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a good way using `inotifywait` & [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
cd /path/to/dir
inotifywait -m -e modify  -r . |
while read a; do
    [[ $a =~ MODIFY[[:space:]]+(myfile1.txt|anotherfile.gz|thisonetoo.tar) ]] &&
    du -h "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

### Note

This have the advantage to avoid *polling* every N seconds.

> inotify is an inode-based filesystem notification technology. It provides possibility to simply monitor various events on files in filesystems. It is a very much powerful replacement of (obsolete) dnotify. inotify brings a comfortable way how to manage files used in your applications.

See [inotify doc](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=about&lang=en)

(It's just a start, you need a bit more code to have the desired output, but this will be easy now)

Comment: please note that this approach is limited to a small amount of files. it is not feasable for many hundreds more files.

Comment: @twall Why ? Any related links ? Can you define precisely "a small amount of files" ?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110245/inotify-fd-why-is-the-limit-per-user-id-and-not-per-process
so the limit is set in /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances and might not be changable depending on your setup (root needed)

Comment: I ended up using a PHP script for this as my system didn't seem to support inotify. But, kudos to the best answer.